# How to assign different interfaces to a single variable in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

As far as I understood it is possible to tell TypeScript that a variable can have different types in declaration. So I tried the following (simplified example):

```
class TypeA {
    public a:number;
}

class TypeB {
    public b:string;
}

class Example {
    private selected: TypeA | TypeB;

    test() {
        if (this.selected instanceof TypeA) {
            console.log(this.selected.a)
        }

        if (this.selected instanceof TypeB) {
            console.log(this.selected.b)
        }
    }
}
```

But now I get the following compilation error:

```
error TS2339: Property 'a' does not exist on type 'TypeA | TypeB'.
```

What did I wrong and how can I do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: I don't see any errors in this code. What version of TS are you using? See https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.3.3#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCeAHApgQWgbwFDV9YA9gHYQAuATgK7CkHkAUilARiAJbDRgBc0RlAW2bJyASkwBfANxYJWLKEgwEKAEKYceQiQrVaDJqw7RmvMuTZEA5uIzTZ8xVGgBRAB5gBiEMg158xOZ6dIwWAG5gpL4QyD40yAAmvCpo0AA+cEjIqrb2-tDy-lFk9Laa+dBsAGbQ9KQAFmwQAHQxcVEJlTpgRMDIBDUpqGUVFdoQBD7NIARWdY0tbcjxCc1gouX5cpv+1bUNTa2xyx1dZD19A5lqI6P+45PI07Pzh0srzcwbd3L+chJAA

Comment: @Lesiak its TS 4.1

Comment: I think you have oversimplified the example, the code you presented if fine (apart form props not being initialized). Are you able to share a reproducible example (preferably in TS playground)?

Comment: No repro as well. Please, post a minimal *reproducible* example. Reproducible means make the error appear in the Playground (sigh - I wish we could force playground links for TypeScript questions...)

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you don't have an initializer or that your properties are not initialized. You could do this:

```
class TypeA {
    public a:number = 0;
}

class TypeB {
    public b:string = '';
}

class Example {
    private selected: TypeA | TypeB | any = null;

    constructor(){
        this.selected = new TypeB();
        this.selected.b = "100.01";
    }

    test() {
        if (this.selected instanceof TypeA) {
            console.log(this.selected.a)
        }

        if (this.selected instanceof TypeB) {
            console.log(this.selected.b)
        }
    }
}
```